# Get MethodInfo of String.Trim with reflection?

Tags: c#, string, reflection, methodinfo

I can get `MethodInfo` of `String.Trim` as follows, It's OK but gotten method info doesn't have a string parameter! Is it OK?

```
typeof(string).GetMethod("Trim", new Type[ ] {});
```

The following code return null, why?:

```
typeof(string).GetMethod("Trim", BindingFlags.Public);
```

And how can we use (invoke) `Trim` method info?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since in your first example, you specifically ask for a method that has no parameters, you get the overload without any parameters.

If you want the overload with parameters, you need to say so:

```
typeof(string).GetMethod("Trim", new [] { typeof(char[]) });
```

To invoke an instance method via `MethodInfo`, you need to pass the instance reference to the `Invoke()` method:

```
// Parameterless overload
methodInfo.Invoke(myStringInstance, null);

// Single-parameter overload
methodInfo.Invoke(myStringInstance, new [] { new [] { ' ', '\r', '\n' } });
```

In your second example, you specified neither `BindingFlags.Instance` or `BindingFlags.Static`, so (as documented) the method returned `null`. Specify one or the other (`BindingFlags.Instance` for the `Trim()` method) to get a valid return value (assuming only one method matches...in this case, there is more than one so you'll get an error).

Comment: any flag specifying will work? i  mean Static or instance both will work in this case? @Peter

Comment: No...the flag you specify has to match the kind of method. You specify `BindingFlags.Static` when you want a static method, and `BindingFlags.Instance` when you don't (i.e. the method is an instance method). Basically: all of the parameters you pass to `GetMethod()` have to both match and uniquely identify the method you want.

Answer (score 2):

When you do `typeof(string).GetMethod("Trim", new Type[ ] {});`, you are asking to retrieve the overload of the method which does not take any parameters. That is why there is no parameter shown in the output. If instead you do this `typeof(string).GetMethod("Trim", new Type[ ] {typeof(char[])});`, it will return the corresponding overload.

Regarding the second issue, you can overcome this problem by setting the flag for indicating instance method i.e. `BindingFlags.Public|BindingFlags.Instance`. This will however, merely change the error to an ambiguous match issue. I would suggest you pass in the parameter type list as well to overcome that.